# Apache Tomcat not asking to login

Tags: server, login, tomcat

I installed Apache Tomcat 8.5.23 on Ubuntu 16.04, and when I try to open welcome page of tomcat on port 8080 it works good. But, when I try to open Manager app, I have a 403 Access Denied error. Tomcat don't show me login window. My `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was found the answer. I was created the `manager.xml` file on `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml` path.
In file I was put this text:

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
```

Hope it helps anyone!